# vercel doployment error "Failed to compile. Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.css' in '/vercel/path0/src' "

Tags: css, reactjs, vercel

I want to deploy my react app on vercel but while building is happening it shows this error:

[image]

I tried to capitalize app.css to App.css but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question, but I experienced this issue with a new project I deployed today on Vercel.

Too resolve it, you just need to change your 'app.css' file (if you have one) to 'App.css' and then re-run your build. Redeploying to Vercel should then go through fine.